# Emacs: open large files in external apps automatically

Tags: elisp

I would like to use Emacs as file manager too and open large file (in dired or speedbar) with `xdg-open`. Can I use `defadvice` for `abort-if-file-too-large` function and how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Advising `abort-if-file-too-large` requires that it still raise an error even if it opens the file externally, otherwise `find-file-noselect` will still try to open the file. Also, you want to call the external program only when the operation type passed to `abort-if-file-too-large` indicates a file is being opened. Something like the following will work, though you might want to tweak the arguments to [`call-process`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Synchronous-Processes.html) to make it fit your scenario better:

```
(defun open-outside-emacs (orig-fun size op-type filename)
  (if (not (string-equal op-type "open"))
      (apply orig-fun size op-type filename)
    (call-process "/usr/bin/xdg-open" nil 0 nil (expand-file-name filename))
    (error "opened externally")))
(advice-add 'abort-if-file-too-large :around #'open-outside-emacs)
```